# Xamarin forms value does not bind to UI from viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a chat application in xamarin.forms. For rest of all my screens I am not using MVVM pattern. But I am trying to implement MVVM pattern in chat portion. So basically my chat view is a listview with incoming and outgoing message template.I will try to call a API in my viewmodel and trying to bind  the result into view.I can get the value from API but can't  make it bind to view.

In order to get the API result, I need to pass a unique id fetched from previous page when user click on chat option.So I have two doubts.

1. As I said I am not using MVVM pattern, I pass the unique ID from previous page to chat page view model through messaging center. Is this the correct way to pass value from one code behind to another page viewmodel?
2. The message does not bind to the UI.

**My viewmodel**

```
public class ChatPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{      

    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<NCMessage> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<NCMessage>();
    public string TextToSend { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<ChatData> ChatListObj;

    public ICommand OnSendCommand { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ChatPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, "ChatClicked", async (value) =>
        {
            string receivedData = value.Myvalue;
            await loadChatList(value.Myvalue);
        });

        OnSendCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextToSend))
            {
                var urlStr = TextToSend;         
                var message = new NCMessage
                {
                    Text = urlStr.ToString(),
                    IsIncoming = false,
                    MessageDateTime = DateTime.Now
                };
                Messages.Add(message);
                TextToSend = string.Empty;
            }

        });

    }

    // My chatlist API call
    public async Task loadChatList(string Type)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {                                  
                NCAPICall callForNotificationList = new NCAPICall("MyHeader", null, null);
                try
                {
                    ChatListObj = callForNotificationList.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<ChatData>>();
                    if (ChatListObj[0].success)
                    {       
                        // This value not updating  in UI
                        Messages.Insert(0, new NCMessage() { Text = "Sample msg", IsIncoming = true });
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {                       
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        });
    }        
}
```

If I provide `Messages.Insert(0, new NCMessage() { Text = "Sample msg", IsIncoming = true });`directly into viewmodel, it will show.

**My ChatPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class ChatPage : ContentPage
    {
       ChatPageViewModel vm;
        public ChatPage(NCDatamodel.Result notificationListData)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = vm = new ChatPageViewModel(Navigation)           
        }    
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `public async void loadChatList(string Type)` .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT The problem was, messeging center will hit early. But how can I pass a certain value from previous xaml.cs to chatpage's viewmodel without messeging center?

Comment: Could you share a sample with static data so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Your event fires before you subscribe to it. Depending on how you navigate to your page you could either add a parameter to its constructor and pass it into the ViewModel from code behind, or you use Dependency Injection and an Inversion of Control container.

Comment: @FlaGon yes thats exactly what I want.  I can pass the parameter to the costrcutor of chatpage. But how to pass it to the viewmodel. Can you help me/

Comment: `callForNotificationList.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<ChatData>>()` this line, shouldn't have an await or is it synchronous ?

Comment: And also, if you debug, do you enter in this condition `if (ChatListObj[0].success)` ?

Comment: @Greggz Thanks for your reply.  The problem was messeging center will hit too early

Comment: If the problem is fixed add your answer then

Comment: @Greggz sure bro

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty approach would be to set a public property in your ViewModel from the constructor of ChatPage.
Then you can override OnAppearing in ChatPage and call loadChatList.